# Scheduling very large amounts of jobs on python luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I've written a Luigi pipeline to extract 1.2 mio files and then do some sed work on them - see https://gist.github.com/wkerzendorf/395c85a2955002412be302d708329f7f.

If I run this through Luigi on a few thousand files it schedules fine. But running this on the whole dataset it complains with `Failed connecting to remote scheduler`. Not sure if I do this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against creating a separate task for each file when there are going to be more than 1k. You will probably have better luck creating a batch task that runs on a directory of those files. This task can then use multiprocessing to exploit parallel calls to your processing function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import os

class TestTask(luigi.WrapperTask):
    inglob = luigi.Parameter(default='/1002/*.gz')
    outdir = luigi.Parameter(default='/1002-out/')
    tmpdir = luigi.Parameter(default='/1002-tmp/'

    def extract_file(filename):
        # extract file to self.tempdir not shown

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.outdir)

    def run(self):
        os.makedirs(self.tempdir)
        p = Pool(cpu_count())
        p.map(extract_file, glob(self.inglob))
        os.rename(self.tempdir, self.outdir)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why does Luigi not cope with that? What I want is to build a system that define pipelines for that run independently and that I can easily rerun from any specific point. Being based on the file system would be great. I've seen a need for a framework like this many times - I wonder like this does not exist. Do you know if airflow would be more suited?

Comment: It's unnecessary overhead for any batch system to make millions of network calls and track the status of individual records through the system. For a batch system, you just need a way to create batches. Luigi does let you rerun your process from any point, so if you have several transformations, you can re-run from step 1 (unzip), 2 (process text), 3 (insert to db), or 4 etc. It is less useful to re-run from having half of a batch completed, you just need to adjust batch sizes until it makes sense as the atomic processing unit.

Comment: That said, if you did want to recover after a partial completion in this model, you would want to move the gz files to a "done" folder or something like that, so the next run would just pick up the files that aren't completed yet.

Comment: This seems to completely defeat the purpose of luigi. Essentially, we self-parallelize and we check if the target exists or not. Essentially then luigi does not provide anything further - right?

Comment: Luigi is not a general parallelization framework. I have it in use for very complex, multi-step pipelines, where sometimes one step fails, and you need to restart from that step. Some of these use things like Apache Spark in the pipeline itself to do distributed parallel processing. Luigi has task types specifically designed for pyspark that makes this possible.